# Retrofit changing Query params dynamically

Tags: android, retrofit2

i'm doing and ex that i need to change the **URL** dynamically, in this case, is the tv channel string in the URL,

The endpoint :

```
/Program/v7/Programs/NowAndNextLiveChannelPrograms?UserAgent=AND&$filter=CallLetter%20eq%20%27FOX%27&$orderby=StartDate%20asc
```

in this case I want to change channel name in the **url** with a var
let say that the FOX in the URL gonna change to another string that is represented by other channel ex: CNN.

this is the service I have to query (not the right one probably)

```
@GET("Program/v7/Programs/NowAndNextLiveChannelPrograms")
    Call<EPGResponse> getEPG( @Query("UserAgent") String userAgent, @Query("$filter") String callLetter,@Query("$orderby") String startDate);
```

My call looks like this:

```
 DataService canaisDataService = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance();

        Call<EPGResponse> call = canaisDataService.getEPG("AND", "CallLetter%20eq%20%27TVI%27","StartDate%20asc");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<EPGResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<EPGResponse> call, Response<EPGResponse> response) {
                 epgResponse = response.body();

                if (epgResponse !=null && epgResponse.getValue() != null){

                    epgValueList = epgResponse.getValue();
                    mutableLiveDataEPG.setValue(epgValueList);



                }
            }
```

Ofc isnt working if you guys have any ideias or see errors from my part let me know, thank you!

Comment: Not very clear which field you want to change exactly. Do you want to replace `NowAndNextLiveChannelPrograms` dynamically?

Comment: @AbhriyaRoy, yes, i think, i just want to be able to pass a new value to the channel, if you see the URL you can see a string "FOX", i want that part of the url can be changed, i tried path but dsnt work. i saw some exemples of queries but im still confused

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change base url, you can try this:

```
@GET("{fullUrl}")
Call<EPGResponse> getEPG(@Path("fullUrl") fullUrl, @Query("UserAgent") String userAgent, @Query("$filter") String callLetter,@Query("$orderby") String startDate);
```

Comment: I think the only thing that need to be changed is this part %27FOX%27 the channel, because if i replace in FOX to CNN or Other value the api result change